# "HibernateException: No Session found for current thread" when calling DAO from Transactional service method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a service bean that loads objects from the database after instantiation into an object cache. If I label the service method that calls my DAO object method as @Transactional, then I get the "HibernateException: No Session found for current thread" error. However, if I label the DAO class as @Transactional, I get no such error and it works fine.

The problem is that I can't then make multiple DAO calls from the same method in the service object and have it be one transaction. Are there any thoughts on what might cause this?

I am using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.

DAO Example:

```java
@Repository
public class HibernateObjectDao implements ObjectDao {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public List<Object> getObjects() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Object").list();
    }
}
```

Service Bean example:

```java
@Service
public class MyServiceBean implements AbstractMyServiceBean
{


    @Resource
    private ObjectDao objectDao;

    private HashMap<String,Object> objectCache;


    public MyServiceBean() {
        this.objectCache = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void setObjectDao(ObjectDao objectDao) {
        this.objectDao = objectDao;
    }


    @Transactional
    public void initialize() {
        loadObjectCache();
    }

    public void loadObjectCache() {
        objectCache.put("stuff",this.objectDao.getObjects())
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml excerpt:

```xml
<bean id="objectDao" class="com.example.persistence.HibernateObjectDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceBean"
    class="com.example.service.MyServiceBean" 
    init-method="initialize">
    <property name="objectDao" ref="objectDao" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are transactional when they're called from the outside of the bean, using an injected instance of the bean, which is in reality a transactional proxy around the actual bean instance.

Spring calls the initialize method directly on the bean instance, not on the transactional proxy, so the methods are not called in a transaction.

Put an initialize method in another bean, which will use an injected MyServiceBean and call its `initialize()` method.

Comment: Couldn't you also move the this.objectDao.getObjects() call outside of the loadObjectCache() method, and make that new method @Transactional, seems like Hibernate is getting confused on what to transact due the dao call being nested within a cache insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no transactional proxy around the bean when Spring calls initialize. This is on purpose, as the philosophy is that the bean is not ready for use until it is init'd.

Some solutions:

- In this special case of init-time data processing, do manual transaction handling via [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) or session.beginTransaction(). If you use JPA/Hibernate, use code like this to add the EntityManager to the Transaction Synchronizer:

  ```
  EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(entityManagerFactory, new EntityManagerHolder(em));
  ```
- Create another bean for all initializing type events in your application and let that call other beans. By that time, all the other beans will be ready and Spring will put a transactional proxy around them. Note: do not call the method set as an init-method from this bean as this way that particular bean will be initialized twice, which is not always healthy :) Create another method for this purpose.
- Use an [ApplicationListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html). With this one, you can register a callback and handle the [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) as a sign that the context initialization is done.